# Hibernate HQL from child to parent table using left join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

In the model there are two tables: person , role

PersonRole java class models the N:M relationship. It has two @ManyToOne attributes:
Person person,  Role role

I have one HQL query to retrieve all users belonging to a role:

```
select role.name, person.name from PersonRole pr join pr.person join pr.role
```

Need to do the other way round: all the roles for a person. But if a person has no roles still need to retrieve the person (left join)

```
select person.name, ro.le.name from PersonRole pr join pr.person join pr.role
```

This is not working as the main entity is PersonRole and returns only users with roles. Dont know how to start the join from Person and go to the optional roles if there is no attribute in the Person entity to reference the role.

how is the best way to do?

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Try this:

Put in your `Person` class a property as follow:

```
List<Role> lstRole;
```

In this way when you'll write your query:

```
SELECT P FROM Person P
```

you'll get for each Person a list af associated roles.

Comment: At the end applied very similar solution. Created new field (List<PersonRole> personRoles) annotated with @OneToMany , and can do in HQL select person.name, role.name from Person person left join person.personRoles proles left join proles.role role. It seems redundant but seems working.

Comment: wanted to get all data in the query because is lazy loaded and there are many rows it would be slow to get all roles in each iteration. cannot use subquery to get all roles object of a person unless use an aggregate function for each field of the roles table instead of getting a list of role objects or having many rows one for each role of the person.

Comment: Ok, have a nice day ;)